# Wordpress mp3 file direct download

Tags: wordpress

Im having a problem in my wordpress. I have this mp3 media that I want to be downloadable then I used different kinds of plugins but no luck. The plugin did work but whenever I clicked the DOWNLOAD button it always play in the browser its not directly downloading.

*see image below*

[image]

and when I clicked DOWNLOAD button it plays in the browser. What I want to achieve is when I clicked the download button it will automatically download.

[image]

Any plugins or alternative solutions are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `download` attribute inside your `a href` as such:

```
<a href="mp3-link.mp3" download="new-or-old-filename.mp3">Download MP3</a>
```